# Using lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to learn list in Haskell but I have a error that I don't understand

I've been trying to definition arguments, but honestly I don't understand too much of haskell yet.

```
lefgNLista:: [Int]->[Int]->Int
lefgNLista []=[]
lefgNLista (fre1:fre2) fre3  = if fre1 == fre3 then 1+lefgNLista else fre1 : lefgNLista fre2
```

Also tried like this but got another error

```
lefgNLista []=[]=0
```

I expect the function to count the amount of N numbers in the list, e.g.

```
ghci> lefgNLista [1,3,5,7,8,8,2,3,8] 8 
3
```

Comment: The fragments are mostly correct. It looks like the desired `countElem` just got interleaved with something like `filter`.

Comment: This seems a little broad to me and doesn't really display a basic understanding of Haskell.  I'm wondering if a tutorial sight might be a better resource for you than StackOverflow at the moment.  Best of luck.

Comment: Well, `fre1 == fre3` is wrong, since `fre1 :: Int` and `fre3 :: [Int]`.

Comment: @HTNW: no, the fragment is wrong several times. For example the code hints that the result should be an `Int`, but the first line returns a list `[]`. As for the second line, that hints that `fre3` should be a list as well, but if we take a look to the body, we check if `fre1 == fre3`, hence we check if the elements are the same, etc.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I was writing an answer before @n.m. posted theirs, and as I saw it, it seemed like the second argument was omitted in the first equation because it was ignored, and `[]` returned because it and `0` are both "empty". The LHSs demonstrated an understanding of pattern-matching, and they seemed to know about recursion and how to consume lists. Yes, the code and formatting was rather borked, but there was a clear specification and the code made a lot more sense with it. It's a lot better than some of the other's beginners' questions under this tag, and it does us well to be nice.

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible definition explained item by item.

I will omit the type. You *can* give this function the type of `[Int]->[Int]->Int` if you want, but it's not the best possible type. The compiler is able to infer the best type for you.

There are two parts in the definition, one for the empty list and one for non-empty lists.

How many elements are in an empty list? Zero. How many of those are equal to any given value? Also zero.

```
lefgNLista [] _ = 0
--         []             ⇒ the empty list
--            _           ⇒ "any given element", we are not looking at it, hence no name
--              =         ⇒ "is defined as"
--                0       ⇒ that's zero
```

OK now let's look at a non-empty list. This part has two further cases. We look at the first element of the list. Either it equals to what we are counting, or not.

```
lefgNLista (x:xs) y | x == y = 1 + lefgNLista xs y
                    | otherwise =  lefgNLista xs y
--         (x:xs)                                  ⇒ A customary way to name a list pattern
--                y                                ⇒ The value we want to count
--                  |                              ⇒ Pronounced "when"
--                    x == y                       ⇒ Self evident
--                           =                     ⇒ "is defined as"
--                             1 + lefgNLista xs y ⇒ Compute for the rest of list and add 1 
--                  | otherwise =                  ⇒ Self evident
--                                 lefgNLista xs y ⇒ Just compute for the rest of list
```

So what is the type of this inferred by Haskell?

```
Prelude λ :t lefgNLista
lefgNLista :: (Num p, Eq t) => [t] -> t -> p
```

This is not as intimidating as it seems. You can read this as "when `p` is some kind of number, and `t` is some kind of stuff you can check for equality, the type is `[t] -> t -> p`". So this function works for `Int`, `Double`, `(Int, Int)` or any other type you can compare — even for other lists!

```
Prelude λ lefgNLista [[1,2], [3,5], [1,2]] [1,2]
2
```

What about `Num p`? `Int` is not the only type you can count with. You may need `Integer` if your lists are *extremely* long, or you may want to use your own fancy number-like type, but this is probably way too advanced at this point.